# Change submit button value on Drupal 8 search form block

Tags: php, drupal, twig, font-awesome

I would like to show a FontAwesome Icon inside a submit button in Drupal 8.

For this i want to change the value for the search form to use the Unicode representation of the icon (`&#xf010;`).

I found infos on how to do this in D7 (https://www.drupal.org/node/154137, https://www.drupal.org/node/45295), but how is it best done it D8? But how would one best do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

After much more reading i finally found the answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197439/how-to-replace-the-search-submit-button-with-a-font-awesome-character/212185#212185

With *hook_form_search_block_form_alter* one can access the search block form directly:

```
function ThemeName_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = html_entity_decode('&#xf002;');
}
```